# React - child-parent relationship with props

Tags: reactjs

I want to have a parent component that its children can register inside, so I can use this data somewhere else (generating a menu, for example).

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
const app = document.getElementById('app');

class Children extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.add(this.props.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Children</div>
    )
  }
}

class Items extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        {this.props.content}
      </nav>
    )
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      sections: []
    }
  }

  add(section) {
    const currentSections = this.state.sections;
    const id = section.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase();
    const obj = { name: section, id };

    this.setState({
      sections: currentSections.push(obj)
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.sections);
    return (
      <div>
        <Items content={this.state.sections} />
        <Children add={this.add.bind(this)} name="Section 1" />
        <Children add={this.add.bind(this)} name="Section 2" />
        <Children add={this.add.bind(this)} name="Section 3" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<Parent />, app);
```

My problem is, `this.state.sections` returns `3`, but when I log it again in `componentDidMount`, it is an array.
What can I do?

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/morepitiqo/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Not sure I'm following correctly... `state.sections` *should* be an array. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Problem is that `state.sections` is an array not in `render` but later, in `componentDidMount`. When I run `console.log(this.state.sections)` in `render` I am getting `3`.

Comment: Oh I see. Added a jsbin for reference

Comment: Thanks! And you see my problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  add(section) {
    const currentSections = this.state.sections;
    const id = section.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase();
    const obj = { name: section, id };
currentSections.push(obj)
    this.setState({
      sections: currentSections
    });
  }
```

Reason is you were setting state to currentSections.push(obj) which actually returns the count not array. Push earlier and set the sections as currentSections

Comment: Great, I knew it's something small ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Actually, mutating in-place is probably not the best option. I would argue use something like `currentSections.concat([obj])` instead, which returns a new array.

Comment: @GoshaArinich You are right, I am using this example only as an example and to learn components communication.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be due to using `push` to append an item, which returns an index of the new element.

Mutating state in-place is not the best option, and I would argue it's better to use `concat` instead:

```
{
  sections: currentSections.concat([obj])
}
```

Which will return a new array.

In your specific case, there's also going to be a race condition between the `add` calls: the three callbacks will be called at approximately the same time, so in all three, `currentSections` will be `[]`. Then each one will append just on item and set it, and ultimately the state is going to end up containing only one element, not three.

To mitigate this, you can use another way of calling `setState` that ensures all three will be added sequentially:

```
this.setState(state => {
  return {
    sections: state.sections.concat([obj])
  };
})
```

Comment: Your solution also works, but causes console warnings: `Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `section-1`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.`